# $.post to display table with for in

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, html-table

i'm trying to display a table with jsonObject response, using loop for, to begin with objetosRetorna.Propiedad_Msg is always not null, so rows in table don't show anything just columns showing a  [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBpUM.png) 
i'm not using AJAX. 
Here is my code. 
    ....

```
 $.post("ListaUser.php",
      { 
        IdPost: DatosJson }, 
        function(objetosRetorna){

          for (var i in objetosRetorna){
            if(objetosRetorna.Propiedad_Msg=='Null'){
              $("#tabla tbody").html(""); 
              var nuevaFila=
              "<tr>"
              +"<td><a href='NewUser.php?a=" + objetosRetorna.Prop_id + "'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default light-green lighten-1'>Editar </button></a> <button type='button' onclick='Eliminar("+objetosRetorna.Prop_id+")' class='red lighten-1 btn btn-danger '>Eliminar</button></td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_titulo+"</td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_propiedad+"</td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_categoria+"</td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_direccion+"</td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_colonia+"</td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_coordenadas+"</td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_superficie+"</td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_recamaras+"</td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_imagenes+"</td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_precio+"</td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_antiguedad+"</td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_fecha+"</td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_descripcion+"</td>"
              +"<td>"+objetosRetorna[i].Prop_prop_id+"</td>"
              +"</tr>";
              $(nuevaFila).appendTo("#tabla tbody");
            }
            if (objetosRetorna.Propiedad_Msg!="Null") {
              var nuevaFila =
              "<tr>"
              +"<td colspan='5'><center><font color='red'>"+objetosRetorna.Propiedad_Msg+"</font></center></td>"
              +"</tr>";
              $(nuevaFila).appendTo("#tabla tbody");
            }
          }

        },"json");
```

> Json Response

```
 [{"Prop_id":"32",
    "Prop_titulo":"Mi titulo de propiedad",
    "Prop_propiedad":"Casa",
    "Prop_categoria":"Renta",
    "Prop_direccion":"Calle Term",
    "Prop_colonia":"Progreso",
    "Prop_coordenadas":"499965",
    "Prop_superficie":"40m2",
    "Prop_recamaras":"5",
    "Prop_imagenes":"imagenes",
    "Prop_precio":"4500","Prop_antiguedad":"15 a\u00f1os","Prop_fecha":"0000-00-00",
    "Prop_descripcion":"Departamen","Prop_prop_id":"10",
    "Propiedad_Msg":"Null"}....]
```

Thank you. 
Hope somebody can help me

> UPDATE.... TypeError: objetosRetorna.map is not a function[Saber más]index.php:62:30

```
function(objetosRetorna) {

              var rows = objetosRetorna.map (function(objeto){

              if (objeto.Propiedad_Msg == 'Null') {
            return "<tr>" +
              "<td><a href='NewUser.php?a=" + objeto.Prop_id + "'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default light-green lighten-1'>Editar </button></a> <button type='button' onclick='Eliminar("+objeto.Prop_id+")' class='red lighten-1 btn btn-danger '>Eliminar</button></td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_titulo+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_propiedad+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_categoria+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_direccion+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_colonia+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_coordenadas+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_superficie+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_recamaras+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_imagenes+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_precio+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_antiguedad+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_fecha+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_descripcion+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+objeto.Prop_prop_id+"</td>"+
              "</tr>";

            } 
            return "<tr>" +
              "<td colspan='5'><center><font color='red'>"+objeto.Propiedad_Msg+"</font></center></td>"+
              "</tr>";

            });

        $("#tabla tbody").html(rows.join(""));
       }
    );
```

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the JSON your server returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects, {}, in JavaScript does not have the method .map(), it's only for Arrays, [].

So in order for your code to work change data.map() to data.props.map()

And json response to something like

```
{"props":[
{"Prop_id":"32"},
{"Prop_titulo":"Mi titulo de propiedad"},
{"Prop_propiedad":"Casa"}, 
{"Prop_categoria":"Renta"}, 
{"Prop_direccion":"Calle Term"},
 ...]}
```

Something to read .map() on:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

PS. if you just want to iterate json and you can make your props into array you can iterate objects like this:

```
for (var key in objetosRetorna) {
  if (objetosRetorna.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
  }
}
```

If you need more in-depth fix or explanation please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the entry you're looping over. Instead of

```
for (var i in objetosRetorna){
    if(objetosRetorna.Propiedad_Msg=='Null'){
```

you would want

```
for (var i in objetosRetorna){
    if(objetosRetorna[i].Propiedad_Msg=='Null'){
    // --------------^^^
```

You make the same small mistake later with `objetosRetorna.Prop_id` a couple of times.

**But**, `for-in` isn't the correct way to loop through an array. You have [lots of options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript), but here I'd probably use `forEach`.

Also, unrelated, but you have

```
if (objetosRetorna.Propiedad_Msg == 'Null') {
```

and then immediately after that

```
if (objetosRetorna.Propiedad_Msg != 'Null') {
```

In that situation, you can just use `else` to avoid the maintenance issue of having the condition repeated.

You're also removing everything from the table when adding *each* row, which means you'll end up with just the last row. So instead of `forEach`, let's use `map` to return an array of row strings:

So taking all that together (see `***` comments):

```
$.post("ListaUser.php", {
        IdPost: DatosJson
    },
    function(objetosRetorna) {
        // *** Note use of `map` to get a string for each row
        var rows = objetosRetorna.map(function(objecto) { // *** We receive each entry as the `objecto` argument
            // Use `objeto` for the various things below
            if (objeto.Propiedad_Msg == 'Null') {
                return "<tr>" +
                    "<td><a href='NewUser.php?a=" + objeto.Prop_id + "'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default light-green lighten-1'>Editar </button></a> <button type='button' onclick='Eliminar(" + objeto.Prop_id + ")' class='red lighten-1 btn btn-danger '>Eliminar</button></td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_titulo + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_propiedad + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_categoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_direccion + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_colonia + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_coordenadas + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_superficie + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_recamaras + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_imagenes + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_precio + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_antiguedad + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_fecha + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_descripcion + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + objetos.Prop_prop_id + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
            }
            // It's not null
            return "<tr>" +
                    "<td colspan='5'><center><font color='red'>" + objeto.Propiedad_Msg + "</font></center></td>" +
                    "</tr>";
        });
        // *** Now we replace the table contents with the strings (joined into one string)
        $("#tabla tbody").html(rows.join(""));
    }
);
```

Comment: I was checking my code,but i dont  understand why im getting a TypeError Message about objetosRetorna.map is not a function.